# How to use Rf with PAM8403 amplifier

Tags: amplifier, power-amplifier

In datasheet of PAM8403 written:
"[image]"

With Ri it is clear, but naturally I did not realized where to connect Rf?
My assumption - one of output pins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rf is the fixed value negative feedback resistor inside the chip (142k) and you define the gain by the value of the external resistor (Ri) >= 18k.

Comment: Jans, thank you for answer, but in different datasheets it is different (compare https://www.laskakit.cz/user/related_files/pam8403.pdf 
 and https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/115/PAM8403-247318.pdf)  it is writtern (p.)

Comment: and also it is written maximum Rf is 85kOhm, if it is fixed, what the reason write that it is a maximum value?

Comment: Interesting, the datasheet with 142k is much newer, maybe there was a bugfix. Resistors inside chips often have +/-30% production tolerance. There is no upper limit for Ri but too low values are critical. With 22k you are on the safe side. Use proper grounding and bypass cap.

Comment: Thank you very much, Jens!